# WebRTC with web audio

Tags: firefox, webrtc, web-audio-api

I'm using WebRTC in Firefox and trying to get the following to work: take a remote MediaStream from a peer (given through PeerConnection), filter it through web audio, and then send the resulting stream to another peer (again through PeerConnection). I hear this is possible in Chrome (or at least the latter 2 parts), but I can't seem to get this to work in Firefox. Does anyone know if it's even possible at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

It's not yet quite possible, at least not in Chrome.  We're working on it.